# Unity3D game apk works pefectly in Emulator, but not in real device ?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-emulator

so I am having this little problem, I have a 3D game in Unity3D that I tried to test on my device but it seems like it not working, not 100%, but I can see my player running but when he dies, the game stop responding as it is in my emulator or Unity, I don't know the reason why, I tried some solution like making changes in files such as 'AndroidManifest.xml' and 'build.gradle' but still have the same problem, also my Admob test Ads are working fine in my emulator but in my phone are ot showing, I tried also to read errors in my logout but I could not understand what was that, it was hard for me to understand it, I am asking here after wasting about 3 days looking here and there with no solution, I had other problems that I've fixed but this one, I could not do it.

Changes I made in AndroidManifest.xml was :

```
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
  android:targetSdkVersion="28" />

  my target was 19 and was not working
```

( Nothing worked so I started playing with numbers, maybe one of them will works but nothing works )

My Android version in emulator is 4.0 but in my phone it is 7.0, 
the SDK components I am using on my pc : 
   -- Android SDK Platfrom 28 ( 8 )
   -- my build Tools : 28.0.1

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not change manifest file. that is also cause of error. used updated unity version. 2018 or 2017. 
Also check admob SDK updated or not.